# How to have a function like color overlay with color blend mode without using ImageMagick

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I want to manipulate an image using php only with the result like the color blend mode in photoshop. I hope you can help me.

I have this code but it returns an image that is like a screen blend mode.

```
<?php
$img="text.png";
$to="";
$bool="";
$imres=$img;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('text.png');
    // $from=$_POST['oldhex'];

    $to=$_POST['newhex'];
    //conversion of hex to rgb values

    // Get width and height
    // $w = imagesx($im); 
    // $h = imagesy($im);
    // $im= imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);



    ![enter image description here][1]$r = hexdec(substr($to, 0, 2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($to, 2, 2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($to, 4, 2));
    /* R, G, B, so 0, 255, 0 is green */

    if($im && imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE, $r, $g, $b,30)&& imagealphablending($im, true)){// echo 'Image successfully shaded';


        imagepng($im, '5.png');
        $bool="true";
        $imres="5.png";
    }
    else{
        echo 'shading failed.';
    }
}
?>
```

This is the input image

[image]

This is the image that I get...

[image: failed image]

This is the image that i want to have[image]

Comment: Can you post the image you get and the image you want?

Comment: Can you add your input image too please?

Comment: there's the input image.

Comment: And, finally hopefully, what value of `newhex` should produce that?

Comment: FFCC33 is the newhex..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had a try at this and got somethimng fairly similar to what you want - maybe it will give you some ideas for further experimentation. Basically I create another image the same size as yours and fill it with a colour wash and transparency and then blend them.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php

    $im = imagecreatefrompng('text.png');

    $to='FFCC33';
    //conversion of hex to rgb values

    $r = hexdec(substr($to, 0, 2));
    $g = hexdec(substr($to, 2, 2));
    $b = hexdec(substr($to, 4, 2));

    $wash=imagecreatetruecolor(225,225);
    $col = imagecolorallocatealpha($wash,$r,$g,$b,70);
    imagefill($wash,0,0,$col);

    imagelayereffect($im,IMG_EFFECT_ALPHABLEND);
    imagecopy($im,$wash,0,0,0,0,225,225);
    imagepng($im,'5.png');
?>
```

Comment: it a great improvement to what i have done.it is close enough.it is just lighter than what i want but thanks for your help.this will help me a lot.